# Retrieve one row based on two rows from the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

The result I want to retrieve is presented below. I have managed to retrieve origin, destination, departure, arrival and priceAmount as I want to but I cant figure out how to get the minimum seats from both of the trips and the drivers operating both of the trips. Dont worry with the fact that driverName is not atomic.

[image: Result I want to retrieve]

My query so far:

```
SELECT t1.origin, t2.destination, t1.departure, t2.arrival, t1.priceAmount + t2.priceAmount AS priceAmount
    FROM trip t1, trip t2
    WHERE t1.origin = 'Stockholm'
    AND t1.destination = 'Copenhagen'
    AND t2.origin = 'Copenhagen'
    AND t2.destination = 'Berlin';
```

Here's the trip table:

```
create table trip(
    tripId serial not null,
    origin varchar(50) not null,
    destination varchar(50) not null,
    departure timestamp not null,
    arrival timestamp not null,
    driverPnr varchar(13),
    priceAmount integer not null,
    seats integer not null,
    primary key (tripId),
    foreign key (origin) references busstop(city),
    foreign key (destination) references busstop(city),
    foreign key (driverPnr) references driver(driverPnr)
);
```

Comment: u min u want to a Select rows with same id but different value in other column?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. I want to retrieve a new row based out of the top two rows. I have successfully been able to retrieve origin, destination, departure, arrival and the combined priceAmount. Though I cant figure out how to get the mininum value of seats from both rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `LEAST` function is what you want:

```
LEAST(t1.seats, t2.seats)
```

If the cross join is deliberate, the query becomes more readable if you use

```
FROM trip t1 CROSS JOIN trip t2
```

Comment: Thank you, that returned what I was expecting!